# Scrapy xpath is not working perfectly, return empty data

Tags: python, parsing, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the book title price and author from vitalsource.com.

I successfully extracted the title, author and ISBN information but I can't get the price from the webpage.

I don't understand why I can't get the data since they are all on the same webpage.

I googled and tried many hours and now it's 4:43 am here, I am tired and despair, please help me.

[please check the image for more detail. The xpath is working fine in the blue area, but not working in the red area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBdUB.png)

```
import scrapy
from VitalSource.items import VitalsourceItem
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider

class VsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'VS'
    allowed_domains = ['VitalSource.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.vitalsource.com/products/cengage-unlimited-1st-edition-instant-access-1-cengage-unlimited-v9780357700006']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = VitalsourceItem()
        item['Ebook_Title'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/h1/text()').extract()[1].strip()
        item['Ebook_Author'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/p/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['Ebook_ISBN'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/h2/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['Ebook_Price'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/span[1]/span[3]/span[2]/text()')
        print(item)
        return item
```

**Result Information:**

```
{
 'Ebook_Author': 'by: Cengage Unlimited',
 'Ebook_ISBN': 'Print ISBN: \n 9780357700037, 0357700031',
 'Ebook_Price': [],
 'Ebook_Title': 'Cengage Unlimited, 1st Edition [Instant Access], 1 term (4 months)'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you want to strictly use xpath, but I will post how it's done both with xpath and css selector:

css:

```
response.css('.u-pull-sixth--right+ span::text').get().strip()
```

xpath:

```
response.xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[1]').xpath('//span[@class]//span[2]/text()').get().strip()
```

Result:

```
{'Ebook_Price': '119.99'}
```

Comment: Do you know why this does not work? Combining it into one xpath

 
 
 
 `response.xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[1]//span[@class]//span[2]/text()').extract()`

Comment: I am a starter programmer, thank you so much for explaining this for me.

Comment: may I ask how did you get the XPath you are showing? the XPath I got was directly copied and pasted from chrome. is the browser analysis the XPath differently than scrapy?

Comment: First I got the xpath of the parent element. then I went down to the price element from there. and if you are asking on "how" I got the xpath value, I used a chrome extension named ChroPath.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will check it out.

Comment: May I ask why the Xpath vaule I got from chrome or ChroPath can't be used directly in scrapy?

Comment: @CongLuo I am not sure why it’s like that.